# Change image on button click in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have four buttons on a view controller..ViewControllerA.On click of ecah button a viewcontroller in container view opens.I want when button A is clicked then the image on button A changes and image on button B,C,D remains same .when button B is clicked then the image on button B changes and image on buttonA,C,D remains same.
when button C is clicked then the image on button C changes and image on buttonA,B,D remains same.when button D is clicked then the image on button A changes and image on buttonA,B,C. remains same

```
- (IBAction)AClick:(id)sender {
    [_A_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@“Ahover.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [_B_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@“B.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
  [_C_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@“C.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
   [_D_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@“D.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
 __A_btn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
}
```

I ma following this code .kindly suggest the changes required as it is not working as desired.

Comment: Are you want to change same button image or different? here i am seeing _A_btn, _B_btn, _C_btn, _D_btn. are they same??

Comment: They are different when A changes i want the rest to remain same

Comment: Then are chnaging A button image ?? I am not seeing the code just set image for normal state for btn A

Answer (score 2):

first set images for buttons for required states as well, and u can change state of the button on click as follows , it will show the image of that state.

```
- (IBAction)AClick:(UIButton *)sender {
      sender.selected = !sender.selected;
 }
```